# Configuring Plugin for parent and child build in a build with several children module

Tags: maven

I have a multi-module Maven build with more than ten children modules and I would like to configure the PMD plugin using a custom ruleset.

My `build` section in the parent pom.xml contain the following entry:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.17.0</version>
    

    <executions>
        <!-- aggregate configuration, parent build-->
        <execution>
            <id>pmd-check-aggregate</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>aggregate-pmd-check</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <printFailingErrors>true</printFailingErrors>
                <rulesets>
                    <ruleset>${project.basedir}/pmd/my-ruleset.xml</ruleset>
                </rulesets>
                <rules>
                    <requireFilesExist>
                        <files>
                            <file>${project.basedir}/pmd/my-ruleset.xml</file>
                        </files>
                    </requireFilesExist>
                </rules>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <!-- aggregate configuration, child build-->
        <execution>
            <id>pmd-check-child</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <printFailingErrors>true</printFailingErrors>
                <rulesets>
                    <ruleset>${project.parent.basedir}/pmd/my-ruleset.xml</ruleset>
                </rulesets>
                <rules>
                    <requireFilesExist>
                        <files>
                            <file>${project.parent.basedir}/pmd/my-ruleset.xml</file>
                        </files>
                    </requireFilesExist>
                </rules>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

However, when I run locally `mvn validate -pl module-c`, I can see in the log the execution id, but the ruleset is ignored. It seems like the configuration of the execution is getting lost or overriden, is this possible at all?

Comment: Where did you place the `<plugin />`? `build/pluginManagement` or `build/plugins`? Do the modules have the appropriate parent?

Comment: Please use the given configuration in the documentation: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/examples/multi-module-config.html

Comment: Good question, build/plugins. The modules have appropriate parent

Comment: @khmarbaise this removes the plugin from the children, but then you cannot launch it with mvn validate -pl module-c, you can only execute aggregate targets

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure about the correctness of the following specification:

```
${project.parent.basedir}/pmd/my-ruleset.xml
```

which looks suspicious (for example, in case of checkstyle that would be just `/pmd/my-ruleset.xml`), however the root cause of your issue is that neither `<rulesets>` nor `<rules>` are parameters of `check` and `aggregate-pmd-check` goals, move that to plugin configuration.

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/examples/multi-module-config.html

Comment: @khmarbaise and what did you want to say?